# Maven dependencyManagement vs dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

How to differentiate programmatically between below two

- Version configured in dependencyManagement section
- Version configured in dependencies section.

When both values are different, it is easy to know but how to differentiate when at both places same value is configured?

Comment: Can you explain for what purpose you want to check programmatically? What kind of problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @khmarbaise
We have a bom which is inherited by many poms. sometimes developers hardcode the dependency in their pom. To notify about this hardcoding i'm developing maven plugin. But unable to notify about this scenario when version coming from bom and version hardcoded in pom are exactly same.

Comment: For such purpose I would suggest to create an maven-enforcer-plugin custom implementation... seemed to be much easier...